# UI Changed, Can't Change It Back

Tags: interface

The interface of many programs has changed to a "classic" look.  Chrome, Firefox, and Virtual Box are three that I've noticed so far.  Everything looks normal when I'm using the file manager or Ubuntu Software Center.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, right click on the desktop and open "Change Wallpaper".  Make sure the theme is set to ambiance.

[image]

Then make sure there aren't any files called `.gtkrc` or `.gtkrc-2.0` in your home folder.  Delete any you find.  Logout and log back in.

Note:  files beginning with a `.` (period) are hidden.  To view them in Nautilus press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or use `ls -a` in a terminal.